# how to print from bash function?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm pretty much new to bash scripting and faced the following problem:

```
my_foo(){
    echo "Some helpful log message"
    #do something useful
}
```

The problem is `my_foo` simply returns `"Some helpful log message"` which is incorrect. But I want to just log this message. How to do that in bash?

I tried

```
my_foo(){
    $(echo "Some helpful log message" > /dev/stdout)
    #do something useful
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What's with the command substitution?

Comment: Anyhow, logs should be sent to stderr, not stdout -- contents written to stderr aren't captured by command substitutions. But you *shouldn't be using a command substitution here at all*.